# JS date object converted to string via socket?

Tags: javascript, sockets

Apparently the date object I'm creating as part of a message block is automatically converted into a string after passing through socket. Namely this code:

```
    $('form').submit(function() {
        var now = new Date();
        var msgObj = {
            'now' : now,
            'text' : "hello"
        };
        console.log(msgObj);
        socket.emit('message', msgObj);
        $('#m').val('');
        return false;
    });

    socket.on('chat message', function(msgObj) {
        console.log(msgObj);
        var now = msgObj.now,
            h = now.getHours(),
            m = now.getMinutes();
        console.log(h+':'+m);
    });
```

prints the following output to console:

```
Object {now: Thu Jun 12 2014 20:49:35 GMT+0100 (BST), text: "hello"}
Object {now: "2014-06-12T19:49:35.258Z", text: "hello"}
```

So the date object turned into a string in between. The final console log then fails because string obviously has no `getHours()` method. Why does this value change? The code that handles the broadcast is inconspicuous:

```
//...
socket.on('message', function(msgObj) {
    io.emit('message', msgObj);
});
```

Comment: turns it into JSON. you can use a reviver on JSON.parse(), or just call new Date(msgObj.now) to turn it back into an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this...

```
socket.on('chat message', function(msgObj) {
        console.log(msgObj);
        var now = new Date(msgObj.now),
            h = now.getHours(),
            m = now.getMinutes();
        console.log(h+':'+m);
    });
```